# Set the legend alignment of pie chart in Kendo Dataviz

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am using kendo ui to render some pie charts to my web page. They have a variable data set, some will have a legend which is 1 row and some will be 2 rows.

When I have the position set to bottom the pie chart with two rows of legend ends up being smaller because its trying to fit the second row in the same area, so it forces the pie chart to be smaller. The legend is displaying how I would like it to display though, with the items being center aligned.

I've tried to get around this by setting the legend position to custom instead of bottom. This takes the legend out of the sizing equation and positions it absolutely. This means that the pie chart sizes are now all the same, but the legend data is now left aligned instead of centered. This makes the legend with only 2 items look bad since its now all off to the left instead of centered.

Does anyone know if there's a way to set the legend to be center aligned while i have it set to using a custom position?

From what I can see in the API documentation, there is no option. Also, because the labels will be of variable lengths, i can't conditionally statically position them because depending on the label length different amounts may fit on each row.

I have setup a JS Bin example showing the issue:

http://jsbin.com/fejeyi/5/

The first two charts are using position bottom and you can see the pie's are different sizes, but the legend displays correctly.

The second two charts are using position custom and you can see the pies are the same size, but the legend is left aligned.

Any help appreciated.

Here's the source of the JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/fejeyi/5/watch?html,js,output

Cheers!